# Display script data comes from database without executing it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting myList from database and append it to my table.

```
$.each(myList, function (index, data) {
    var row = '<tr>';        
    row = row            
        '<td class="action"><a href=\'#\' title=\'Edit Note\' onclick="showPopup(' + '\'' + note.RID + '\'); return false;" ><img width=\'25\' height=\'20\' src=\'../images/text-editor.png\' /></a></td>'
        + '</tr>';        
    $('#tblNotes').append(row);
});
```

if the value of row comes from database is a script then how to show it on my table without executing the script?

One solution is, we can remove the script tag. like this:

```
row = row.replace("<script>", "");
row = row.replace("</script>", "");
```

But I don't want it. I have to show the exact value.

Comment: Change the < to &lt;

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan, I solved this by using the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. 
By using html entity, I solved this.

```
row = row.replace("<script>", "&lt;script&gt;");
row = row.replace("</script>", "&lt;/script&gt;");
```

by adding these lines, I can stop executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

Either will work

```js
var row = `Here is some embedded script <script>alert('bla')<\/script>`

document.getElementById("x").innerText = row

row = row.replace(/</g, "&lt;");

document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = row
```

```html
<span id="x"></span>
<hr/>
<span id="y"></span>
```